# I need help "debugging" an If/Else if/Else statement's syntax

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error, var, multiple-choice

I am creating a game of Rock, Paper, scissors on "Codecademy" so I am using simple JavaScript for this.   There are four necessities for this simple code

- If computerChoice is between 0 and 0.33, make computerChoice equal to "rock".
- If computerChoice is between 0.34 and 0.66, make computerChoice equal to "paper".
- If computerChoice is between 0.67 and 1, make computerChoice equal to "scissors".
- Needs to be an If/Else If/Else statement

So basically, I need to change the  value of the function "computerChoice" based on the value of the function "computerChoice".

```
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random(); {
    console.log(computerChoice);
}

if (computerChoice >= 0 & <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = rock;
}

else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 & < 0.66) {
    computerChoice = paper;
}
else {
    computerChoice = scissors;
}
```

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: You need several lessons in very basic Javascript principles.  I'd suggest to you that it would be more efficient for you to do some studying of basic Javascript syntax rather than ask this level of question here every time you try something for the first time.

Comment: Your question, which looks like one of more general learning would be better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is more geared to code review style questions.  This site is for solving specific issues that you may have.

Answer (score 1):

There are following problems in your code.

**1)** There should be `&&` instead of `&`.

**2)** This condition

```
(computerChoice >= 0 & <= 0.33)
```

should be

```
(computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33)
```

**3)** The `rock`, `scissors` and `paper` should be string, just wrap them in quotes.

**4)** In lines bellow

```
var computerChoice = Math.random(); {
    console.log(computerChoice);
}
```

there is not need of `{` `}` it should be written as

```
var computerChoice = Math.random(); 
console.log(computerChoice);
```

**Combining all in one**

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);


if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = 'rock';
} else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice < 0.66) {
    computerChoice = 'paper';
} else {
    computerChoice = 'scissors';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (computerChoice < 0.33) {
  computerChoice = "rock";  
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.66){
  computerChoice = "paper";    
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Five problems

1. You don't need braces around the `console.log` statement.
2. You need quotes around your values, rock, paper, and scissors (or else define them as variables beforehand).
3. A logical and in JavaScript requires two ampersands `&&`. (A single ampersand is a bitwise operator.)
4. You have to include both sides of the inequality after the logical and. You cannot say `& < 0.66` because JavaScript has no idea what you are referring to, but would need to write `&& computerChoice < 0.66`.
5. A mathematical problem is that you're not quite partitioning the interval from 0 to 1 correctly into three equal segments (and completely leaving out the part between .33 and .34).

## Plus one optimization

- Although 4. is true above, you don't even need the logical `&&` operation at all, because you already know by the time that the code in the `else if`  statement is reached, that the first `if` conditional is not true, and it does not need to be checked again.

There is no variable you defined called `rock`, so you can define one, or just use the string `"rock"`. And the same for `"paper"` and `"scissors"`.

## Suggested revision

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);


if (computerChoice < 1/3) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}

else if (computerChoice < 2/3) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}

else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax needs a bit of fixing.

For one thing, you don't need those curly braces around the `log()` statement.

For another thing, you need a variable to test against in the second part of each if statement:

```
if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = rock;
} else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice < 0.66) {
    computerChoice = paper;
} else {
    computerChoice = scissors;
}
```

Note the `computerChoice` being compared in the second half of each boolean expression.

Also, you haven't defined the variables `rock`, `paper`, and `scissors`. Instead, you can try using the strings `'rock'`, `'paper'`, and `'scissors'`, respectively.